# i'm trying to use customTextField

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-textinputfield

i'm trying to use customTextField
this the file which contain the Widget

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Widget defaultFormField({
  required TextEditingController controller,
  required TextInputType type,
  required Function validate,
  Function? onSubmitted,
  Function? onChange,
  Function? onTap,
  required String label,
  required IconData prefix,
}) =>
    Form(
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: controller,
        validator: (value) => validate(value),
        // validator: validate(),
        onFieldSubmitted: onSubmitted!(),
        onChanged: onChange!(),
        onTap: onTap!(),
        keyboardType: type,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText:label,
            prefixIcon: Icon(prefix),
        border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

and this how i call it
in my home page

```dart
    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          key: scaffoldKey,
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            title: Text(titles[currentIndex]),
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
            onPressed: () {
              if (isBottomSheet) {
                Navigator.pop(context);
                isBottomSheet = false;
                setState(() {
                  fabIcon = Icons.edit;
                });
              } else {
                scaffoldKey.currentState?.showBottomSheet(
                    (context) => Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
                          Form(
                            key: formdKey,
                            child: defaultFormField(
                                controller: titleController,
                                type: TextInputType.text,
                                validate: (String value) {
                                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                                    return 'title must not be empty';
                                  }
                                  return null;
                                },
                                label: 'Title Task',
                                prefix: Icons.title),
                          ),
                        ]));
                isBottomSheet = true;
                setState(() {
                  fabIcon = Icons.add_task;
                });
              }
            },
            child: Icon(fabIcon),
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
              selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
              unselectedItemColor: Colors.black54,
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
              currentIndex: currentIndex,
              onTap: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  currentIndex = value;
                });
              },
              items: const [
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.new_label), label: 'Tasks'),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.check_circle), label: 'Done'),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.archive), label: 'Archive'),
              ]),
          body: screens[currentIndex],
        );
      }
```

Comment: whare error are you getting and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: hi @Ahmad will you please describe your problem clearly

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a class instead of that code, your code is wrong.
This is one of my custom `TextFormField`.
**This contains own another class but anyway you can use this**:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:plasco/config/textfield_validator.dart';
import 'package:plasco/utils/colors.dart';

class PlascoTextFormFild extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? text;
  final FontWeight? fontWeight;
  final double? fontSize;
  final double? counterFontSize;
  final TextAlign? textAlign;
  final TextInputType? keyboardType;
  final int? maxLength;
  final String? hint;
  final int? maxLines;
  final Color? color;
  final TextEditingController? controller;
  final bool? enabled;
  final Validator? validator;
  final bool publicValidator;
  const PlascoTextFormFild(
      {Key? key,
      this.text,
      this.fontWeight,
      this.publicValidator = false,
      this.fontSize,
      this.color = Colors.transparent,
      this.counterFontSize,
      required this.textAlign,
      this.keyboardType,
      this.maxLength = 800,
      this.hint,
      this.maxLines,
      this.controller,
      this.enabled = true,
      this.validator})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PlascoTextFormFildState createState() => _PlascoTextFormFildState();
}

class _PlascoTextFormFildState extends State<PlascoTextFormFild> {
  bool _focused = false;
  bool _hasError = false;
  String _error = '';
  late FocusNode? _keyboardFocus;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _keyboardFocus = FocusNode();
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _keyboardFocus!.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        if (!_keyboardFocus!.hasPrimaryFocus) {
          _focused = false;
        }
      });
    });

    return Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: widget.color,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
        ),
        child: TextFormField(
          controller: widget.controller,
          enabled: widget.enabled,
          cursorHeight: 20,
          textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
          focusNode: _keyboardFocus,
          maxLines: widget.maxLines,
          maxLength: widget.maxLength,
          textAlign: widget.textAlign!,
          keyboardType: widget.keyboardType,
          validator: (text) {
            if (widget.validator == null) {
              if (widget.publicValidator) {
              var a = PublicValidator(text!, widget.text!);
                if (a) {
                  return "";
                } else {
                  return null;
                }
              } else {
                return null;
              }
            } else {
              if (widget.validator!.hasError(text!)) {
                setState(() => _hasError = true);
                _error = widget.validator!.getError();
                return '';
              } else {
                setState(() => _hasError = false);
                return null;
              }
            }
          },
          style: TextStyle(
              color: PlascoColor.Black1,
              fontFamily: 'IRANSansMobile',
              fontSize: widget.fontSize,
              letterSpacing: 0,
              fontWeight: widget.fontWeight,
              height: widget.maxLines != null ? 2 : 1),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            counterText: "",
            labelStyle: TextStyle(
              color: _hasError
                  ? PlascoColor.Red1
                  : _focused
                      ? PlascoColor.Yellow1
                      : PlascoColor.Gray1,
              fontFamily: 'IRANSansMobile',
              fontSize: widget.fontSize,
              letterSpacing: 0,
              fontWeight: widget.fontWeight,
              height: 1,
            ),
            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                color: PlascoColor.Gray2,
                fontFamily: 'IRANSansMobile',
                fontSize: widget.fontSize,
                letterSpacing:
                    0 /*percentages not used in flutter. defaulting to zero*/,
                fontWeight: widget.fontWeight,
                height: 1),
            counterStyle: TextStyle(
                color: PlascoColor.Gray1,
                fontFamily: 'IRANSansMobile',
                fontSize: widget.counterFontSize,
                letterSpacing: 0,
                fontWeight: widget.fontWeight,
                height: 1),
            floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
            // border: OutlineInputBorder(),
            disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                  color: PlascoColor.Gray2,
                  width: 1.0,
                )),
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                  color: PlascoColor.Gray2,
                  width: 1.0,
                )),
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                  color: PlascoColor.Yellow1,
                  width: 1.0,
                )),

            focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                  color: PlascoColor.Red1,
                  width: 1.0,
                )),
            errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                  color: PlascoColor.Red1,
                  width: 1.0,
                )),
            labelText: _hasError ? _error : widget.text,
            hintText: widget.hint,
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 8, 8, 8),
          ),
          // autofocus: false,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```